# Hot to install laravel-vue-i18n-generator package?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, composer-php, vue-i18n

I am trying to implement language translation in my app using the following plugin `vue-i18n`

I am following this documentation

https://github.com/martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator

When I run the following code

```
composer require martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator
```

in `root@d722309335cd:/var/www#`

I get the following error

```
root@d722309335cd:/var/www# composer require martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
---Using version ^0.1.30 for martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update


  [UnexpectedValueException]
  /var/www/vendor/composer does not exist and could not be created.


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You've probably messed up all sorts of permisisons by using Composer as root. Stop doing that - the warning's there for a reason.

Comment: How do I do that without root?

Comment: Run it as a non-root user? https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root